# How to set "textColor" property of button in android 2.1?

Tags: android

I am trying to set "textColor" property of button in android 2.1. But I am unable to set it to correct value ? What is the correct way of setting "textColor" property of a button in android 2.1 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just set hex values to change the color. I was able to find this using some trial/error

e.g. #aa0000 for red.